How do I use Rhythmbox to copy to my iPod?
I have recently moved all my music to Rhythmbox from my iPod. Actually, I thought I was copying it but I've ended up with all the music on my computer, which previously held no music, and seemingly none on the iPod, but read on...
When I look at the iPod within Rhythmbox all the music appears to be there, and will play through the computer. If I look at the iPod Properties tab within Rhythmbox, it appears that there is 4.6Gb of music on it, which is what I expect. Once the iPod is unmounted however, it appears to be empty.
I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS and an Ipod Classic 120Gb
